# Base Object class to automatically have a filter to show un-deleted objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automation, filtering

Sorry for the weak title.

The idea that I have for my website framework is to have the ability to Delete something without actually deleting it from the database, only marking it as deleted, eventually a recycling bin.

One example is if you have an `Album` with a list of `Genres` associated to it, and you delete one of the `Genres` (unrelated to the Album), I would like the `Genre` to stay associated with the Album, allowing the user to change the Genre to something else if needed at a later date.

So with that said, I would like to implement a filter that would be automatically applied to all Objects that Inherit the `BaseObject` below:

```
public class BaseObject
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Oid { get; set; 
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
}
```

After that we have the `Albums` and `Genres` Classes (Inheriting the BaseObject):

```
public class Album : BaseObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AlbumsGenres> Albums { get; set; }
}

public class Genre : BaseObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AlbumsGenres> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure if it is easily possible to have `Collections` auto filter, so that when I create a Controller, I don't need to worry about modifying a return like this:

```
return View(db.Genres.ToList());
```

Any advice that points me in the right direction is appreciated.

I've ventured into ideas like `public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)` within the `public class BaseActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute` Class where it automatically adds a set of objects needed for each page (`ViewBag`), but can't wrap my head around all Object having filtering applied.

Comment: To accomplish this you would want to set a flag for the request somewhere (the RequestContext is a good place to start) that you then use to query for the objects via an intermediary service that automatically handles the business logic. That being said, I can't imagine a scenario where using a filter in this way is a good idea, are you sure a filter is what you need?

Comment: this may help : https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/